the previous implementation of HandlerWrapper for ee8 is no longer available in Jetty 12 due to the removal of the nested package.How to achieve it?
Upgrading from Jetty 9 to Jetty 12, I want the program to be compatible with ee8, ee9, and ee10. However, the previous implementation of HandlerWrapper for ee8 is no longer available in Jetty 12 due to the removal of the nested package. How can I achieve this? Are there any alternative solutions?
public class InfoHandler extends HandlerWrapper{ }
“I need to upgrade my code from Jetty 9 to Jetty 12, and I want it to be compatible with ee8, ee9, and ee10. However, I had previously implemented a custom HandlerWrapper for ee8, but it’s not available in Jetty 12. How can I achieve this? Are there any alternative solutions or a unified interface that I can use?”
I still haven’t found a suitable solution, and you hope I can provide a suitable plan, and I’m very grateful.

See the documentation for the migration guide.

https://jetty.org/docs/jetty/12/programming-guide/migration/11-to-12.html

Sounds like you want a org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler.Wrapper.
See the documentation about the Server Handlers.

https://jetty.org/docs/jetty/12/programming-guide/server/http.html#handler

The Server Handlers are neutral to all the environments (ee11, ee10, ee9, ee8, etc).  If you implement it there then those can exist to cover any environment specific handler you decide to add.
Check also the github.com/jetty/jetty-examples as there are a few Handler.Wrapper implementations there for you.

Thank you for your response, but I want to set the encoding through HttpServletRequest request.setCharacterEncoding(requestCharacterEncoding);  in this way, but the HttpServletRequest class is not available.

Look at the jetty-examples like I pointed out, there's several places that do that.  response.getHeaders().put(HttpHeader.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain;charset=utf-8");

The character encoding is part of the Content-Type response headers, the only reason it is a separate call on the Servlet API is to support the response.getWriter() API, which is not necessary on the jetty-core API.
